# Cannot get CMake to handle Fortran-90 modules properly

Tags: cmake, fortran

I've had a miserable afternoon trying to add a Fortran-90 module to a large multilanguage library set (mostly C++) built with CMake, and am at the point where I am clearly going in circles. There is an amazing dearth of information online that might help me with this, and the CMake documentation is as inscrutable as always.

The library set is too large to boil down properly (so I've been unable to get a good small reproducer) but the essence of is this. Each library lives in its own directory, with a test directory beneath it. I've added an F90 file containing a module to one of the directories, which I'll call `low_library`. The contents of this directory are something like:

```
low_library:
    CMakeList.txt
    file1.cc
    file1.hh
    file2.cc
    file2.hh 
    my_module.f90
    test:
       CMakeList.txt
       test1.cc
       test2.cc
       test3.cc
       my_module_test.f90
```

except many more .cc and .hh files. In the `CMakeList.txt` file for the library directory, I have instructions that include

```
add_library(low_library STATIC "")
target_sources(low_library
  PUBLIC:
    file1.hh
    file2.hh
  PRIVATE:
    file1.cc
    file2.cc
)
```

There's more but it's not obviously relevant.

So the first question is where to put `my_module.f90`. I want `my_module.f90.o` to be included in the `liblow_library.a` file but I need the `my_module.mod` file to be visible to other libraries I'm building (and to users of the library set). So I add the line

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules)
```

towards the top of my CMakeList.txt file, add `my_module.f90` to the PRIVATE part of the `target_sources()` PUBLIC list, and ... *sigh* ... the build system puts the .mod file in the build directory, and not in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules`. The other libraries can't see it and fail to build.

So now I put `my_module.f90` in the PUBLIC part of `target_sources()` and try again. This time the module files goes where I expected it, my test directory can see it and builds successfully, and I'm happy until I move on to building the next library, in directory `high_library` which depends on `low_library`. The build comes up with the truly bizarre error:

```
f951: Fatal Error: Can't rename module file â/scratch/kgbudge/develop/install/fortran_modules/cta_mesh_generator.mod0â to â/scratch/kgbudge/develop/install/fortran_modules/cta_mesh_generator.modâ: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the rest of the trace, it appears that with `my_module.g90` in the public interface of `low_library`, the build for `high_library` ignores what's already in my `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules` and *builds its own copy of the d-mned .mod file* in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules`. Which, since we have high-powered build servers  and always build in parallel (`make -j16` is typical) means a race condition between competing build jobs.

Okay, I know. I needed to include the line

```
target_include_directories(low_library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules)
```

near start of the `CMakeLists.txt` file for `high_library` so it knows where to find the modules and wont' try to build its own.  Except this *doesn't help*.

I can find nothing online that gives me any clues what is going on or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that I had my

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fortran_modules)
```

only in the libraries that produced or consumed the new modules. But other libraries used the library containing the module and needed to see a copy of the module even though they weren't actually using the module. I *think*.

Anyway, moving this line into the root CMakeLists.txt allows me to build the whole library successfully. I still seem some warnings:

```
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory â/srcâ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
```

but at least it all builds.